# Laravel Passport token expiry

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I'm using `Laravel Passport` to authenticate users for my single page application.
I would like the access token to expire if it wasn't used for some time and refresh the expiry time, whenever it is used. I only found a way, to set the expiry time to a fixed time.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all you should show you code so we can help you in a better way.

From what you said you want to set an expire date to you token if not used and when used make the expire date longer.

you can use the Pasport moethods to get the result you need.
Example:

```
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addHours(<Hours you want>));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(<days you want>));
```

Hope this helps
Good luck

Comment: But then I have to use the refresh token to get a new access token when the access token has expired, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Not really it will change the expire date of the token. witch means that the token can be used for a longer time (using a service provider). refreshTokensExpireIn you use for the users who are logging in. so lets say I'm logging in and my token will be expired in 2 days. once i log in it will add (some number lets say 30) more days to my token expire time.  personalAccessTokensExpireIn : you use to set the expire date of a token at the creating time so when at the time that you make the token for the user (create token method) you can add this method.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That's what I have been looking for.

Comment: It does not work the way I thought. When I use the access token, the expiration date remains the same, and when it expires, I would need to use the refresh token to get a new access token. I'd like to extend the validity of the access token when it's in use, so you do not need the refresh token if you use the application often enough.

Comment: Are you using a personal access token or REST ?

Comment: I use the access token from a Password Credentials Grant

Comment: I thought about using a middleware that updates the expires_at field for the token being used. But I hoped that there would be a better way.

Comment: you can use that but i still cant see why you are not using  Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn() at login you can add that to the middle-ware instead of changing the database columns (ugly). you said in you answer (and when it expires, I would need to use the refresh token to get a new access token). in a normal healthy application if your token is expired you need to activate it by receiving an email that has a link make a new token for that user or by making request. Don't mix things up or you will have a big spaghetti board in your hands.

Comment: Both the frontend and the backend are from me. So I do not need emails or anything to get a new token. I can simply let users log in with their username and password. Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn() did not do what I wanted.I want to update the expires_at date if the token is used, so it does not expire if it is used at regular intervals